# angular 4 loading.dismiss() not working

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to do loading.dismiss() inside handleError() method , but not sure how to do?
it is perfectly working while the response is good, not sure how to handle error case

please help

```
@Injectable()
```

export class SharedProvider {

```
 private _postsURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

 constructor(private http: Http, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
 }



 getPosts(): Observable<IPosts[]> {

    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: 'loading...'
      });
      loading.present();
     return this.http
         .get(this._postsURL)
         .map((response: Response) => {
            loading.dismiss();
            console.log("Result printed!!");
             return <IPosts[]>response.json();

         })
         .catch(this.handleError);


 }

  handleError(error: Response) {
      this.loading.dismiss();
     console.log("Err printed!!" + error.statusText);
     return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
 }
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `loading` object doesn't exists in your `handleError` method because it's scoped to `getPosts()` so you can't have access to it, it could be possible if the `loading` was globally set or a property of your class. There's a couple solutions i think that can solve this:

First is dismissing your loading and then calling `handleError`:

```
// your getPosts method ...
.catch(err =>{
  loading.dismiss();
  this.handleError(err);
});
```

The second one (as said) is creating a property `loading` and using it instead of a scoped loading object.

```
 private _postsURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
 public loading;
 constructor(private http: Http, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
 }

 getPosts(): Observable<IPosts[]> {
   this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({ content: 'loading...' });
   this.loading.present().then(() =>{
     return this.http
         .get(this._postsURL)
         .map((response: Response) => {
            this.loading.dismiss();
            console.log("Result printed!!");
             return <IPosts[]>response.json();

         })
         .catch(this.handleError);
   });
 }
```

Also try to wrap your method content in the promise returned by the loading `present()` method, there's a lot of concurrency errors of the method `dismiss()` being triggered before the loading (or any other presentable component) is even shown to the user.

Anyway, one of the solutions may work to you, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot , this helped

Answer (score 2):

Am just going to drop this for Inoic 4 users

```js
const loading = await this.loadingController.create({ message: 'Processing card' })
      loading.present().then( () => {
          getPostFunction({
              data: {email:"test@test.com"}
          }).then((response) => {
              loading.dismiss();
              console.log(response);
          }, (error) => {
               loading.dismiss();
              console.log(error)
          });
      })
```